# При нажатии на Button EditText очищается...

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Добрый вечер, помогите разобраться с EditText, как выводить сообщение, я научился, а как очистить поля, не понял.

```
    final Button btnCheck = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
    final Button btnClean = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClean);
    final TextView txtPassword = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    final TextView vPass = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vPass);

    btnClean.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //TODO chito syda pisat`?
        }
    });
    btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vPass.setText(txtPassword.getText());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`txtPassword.setText("")`

Comment: Спасибо, даже не подумал, что так просто)

Comment: @Verteletsky, а ещё можно вот так:

    txtPassword.getText().clear();

Comment: @SuperCreeper, понял, учту, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

[@Verteletsky](/users/26232/verteletsky), ещё можно так:

```
txtPassword.setText(null);
```