# Android как сделать крестик для очистки поля?

Tags: java, android

Есть поле ввода, в него вводиться сумма, хотелось бы чтобы как нажали на поле, появлялся такой крестик, как знаете в браузере если нажимаешь на строку адреса, справа крестик появляется которым можно ве удалить сразу.

Comment: примерно [так](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/384822/177345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#cccccc" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/delete"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Класс:

```
private EditText editText;
private Button btnClear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
        btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_clear);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher());
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
    }

    private OnClickListener onClickListener() {
        return new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText.setText(""); //очищаем edittext
            }
        };
    }

    private TextWatcher textWatcher() {
    return new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {//проверка на пустоту edittext и в зависимости от этого выводить ли кнопку (х)
                btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                btnClear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
}
```

[Спонсор](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/04/android-edittext-with-cross-button-in.html)

P.S. Оставил именно то, что Вам нужно.

Comment: Вставил я твою кнопку чето не показывает ее ни на моей слое
http://prntscr.com/c7g3od - тут появляются какие то квадратики желтые и красные
ни на новом что я создаю

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг покажи код как вставил